# Sorting 2D numpy array by column index not key value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, sorting

I am working on a Python function to sort a dataset using various sorting algorithms. The dataset I'm working with is the IMDb dataset, and I need to extract specific columns from it depending on the test cases.
for example test 1 I need to sort the data according to startYear

but after running the first test the sorting algorithms seems to sort the dataset according to movieId not the startYear and the test fails

here is the function I used

```
def sorting_algorithms(file_path, columns, select):
    
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    column_vals = [0] + [df.columns.get_loc(col) for col in columns]
    # Convert the dataframe to a 2D array of values
    data = df.iloc[:, column_vals].values.tolist()
  
    if(select==1):
        start_time = time.time()
        output_list = insertion_sort(data, column_vals)
        end_time = time.time()
        time_in_seconds = end_time - start_time
        return [time_in_seconds, list(map(lambda x: x[0], output_list))]
    if(select==2):
        start_time = time.time()
        output_list = selection_sort(data, column_vals)
        end_time = time.time()
        time_in_seconds = end_time - start_time
        return [time_in_seconds, list(map(lambda x: x[0], output_list))]
    if(select==3):
        start_time = time.time()
        output_list = quicksort(data, column_vals)
        end_time = time.time()
        time_in_seconds = end_time - start_time
        return [time_in_seconds, list(map(lambda x: x[0], output_list))]
    if(select==4):
        start_time = time.time()
        output_list = heap_sort(data, column_vals)
        end_time = time.time()
        time_in_seconds = end_time - start_time
        return [time_in_seconds, list(map(lambda x: x[0], output_list))]
    if(select==5):
        start_time = time.time()
        output_list = shell_sort(data, column_vals)
        end_time = time.time()
        time_in_seconds = end_time - start_time
        return [time_in_seconds, list(map(lambda x: x[0], output_list))]
    if(select==6):
        start_time = time.time()
        output_list = merge_sort(data, column_vals)
        end_time = time.time()
        time_in_seconds = end_time - start_time
        return [time_in_seconds, list(map(lambda x: x[0], output_list))]
```

this is the first sorting algorithm

```
def selection_sort(arr, columns):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        min_idx = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
            for col in columns:
                if arr[j][col] < arr[min_idx][col]:
                    min_idx = j
                    break
                elif arr[j][col] > arr[min_idx][col]:
                    break
        arr[i], arr[min_idx] = arr[min_idx], arr[i]
    return arr
```

this is the test function

```
def testcase_1_1():
    global total
    global f
    sorted_testcase_1_1 = sorting_algorithms("testcases_1_2_df.csv", ['startYear'], 2)
    print("Sorted list of movie IDs for test case 1_1: ", sorted_testcase_1_1[1])

    df = pd.read_csv('imdb_dataset.csv', low_memory=False, delimiter=',')
    df = df[df['tconst'].isin(sorted_testcase_1_1[1])].set_index('tconst').loc[sorted_testcase_1_1[1]].reset_index()

    print("Sorted 2D array based on startYear column:\n", df[['tconst', 'startYear']].values)

    prev_start_year = None
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        start_year = int(row['startYear'])
        print("prev_start_year: {}, start_year: {}".format(prev_start_year, start_year))
        if prev_start_year and start_year < prev_start_year:
            print("TestCase 1_1 failed")
            f += 1
            return 0
        prev_start_year = start_year

    print("TestCase 1_1 Passed and your Algorithm Time Complexity = {}".format(sorted_testcase_1_1[0]))
    total += 1
    return sorted_testcase_1_1
```

but after running the first test the sorting algorithms seems to sort the dataset according to movieId not the startYear and the test fails
here what I get
prev_start_year: None, start_year: 2020
prev_start_year: 2020, start_year: 2015
TestCase 1_1 failed

Comment: In your `insertion_sort` algorithm, it seems to suggest `arr` is a 3D array (i.e., you're giving it 3 indices to get the value), however, the `data` that you pass to it will be 2D. I'm guessing that the `data` contains the start years as strings and when you pass the third index in `arr`, e.g., `arr[j][col][1]`, the final `[1]` is actually getting 2nd character in the year string, rather than the whole year.

Comment: I didn't notice that I put the wrong algorithm I putted insertion_sort while I was working with selection_sort

Comment: In `selection_sort` why are you looping over `cols` when you want to sort on one particular column (in your case that would be column `1`, which should contain the start year value)? I'd suggest removing the `for col in columns:` loop and just setting `col = 1`.